# In slider when move to next slide video of that slide freezes

Tags: javascript, animation, video, slider, gsap

Hi i made a slider which is sliding to the next slide based on the duration of the video but the catch is that all of those videos are playing at once thats why when we move from 1st slide to 2nd slide after the duration ends we can see the freezing of that video maybe because the duration of that video already ended. since its not in loop so thats y it stops there ( however it works when i add loop keyword in video element in HTML but not a proper solution to it )

but wherever you're on the slide other than slide 1 when you jump back to slide 1 either by dragging or clicking thumbnail it always plays from the start

Idk how but the 1st slide works

Goals we have to achieve:

- slide should play from start when its on screen

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/raj-shukla/pen/rNKjKzN?editors=0010)

```
// Just for codepen clear the console between refreshes
// gsap.registerPlugin(SplitText, Draggable);
document.querySelectorAll(".slider").forEach((container) => {
    // Setup variables
    const items = container.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
        itemsMax = items.length - 1;
    const thumbnail = container.querySelector(".thumbnails");

    const video = document.querySelector(".slide__figure__video");

    let index = 0;
    const move = 100;
    const timer = video.duration * 1000;

    const duration = 0.5;
    let autoplay;
    //--------------------------------//
    //  Inital setup
    //--------------------------------//
    function init() {
        // Create  Dots
        items.forEach((item, index) => {
            const number = document.createElement("button");
            number.innerHTML = index + 1;

            if (index === 0) number.classList.add("active"); // Set the first dot to active
            // Allow clicking the dots
            number.addEventListener("click", () => {
                slideLogic(false, index);
            });

            if (thumbnail) thumbnail.appendChild(number);
        });
        // Animate the first element in
        gsap.set(items, { autoAlpha: 0 });
        gsap.set([".slider", items[index]], { autoAlpha: 1 });
        gsap.from(items[index], { autoAlpha: 0, x: move });

        autoplay = window.setTimeout(slideLogic, timer);
    }
    // Run inital setup
    init();
    // END  Inital setup --------------//

    //--------------------------------//
    // ☝️ Touch
    //--------------------------------//
    if (window.Draggable) {
        Draggable.create(items, {
            type: "x", // Drag only on the X axis
            zIndexBoost: false,
            onDragStart: function () {
                window.clearTimeout(autoplay); // disable autoplay
                slideLogic(this.getDirection() === "right" ? true : false);
            }
        });
    }
    // END ☝️ Touch  --------------//

    //--------------------------------//
    // Set active  dot
    //--------------------------------//
    function dotActive(index) {
        const dotsAll = thumbnail.querySelectorAll("button");
        dotsAll.forEach((dot) => {
            dot.classList.remove("active");
        });
        dotsAll[index].classList.add("active");
    }
    // END Set active  dot --------------//

    //--------------------------------//
    // ️ Slide animation
    //--------------------------------//
    function slideAnimation(index, moveIn, outIn) {
        // Reset the properties you are animating below
        // Ohter wise they animate from that positon (probalby not visable)
        gsap.set(items, { xPercent: 0, scale: 1 });
        gsap.set(items[moveIn], { autoAlpha: 1 });

        const text = new SplitText(items[moveIn].querySelector("h1"), {
            type: "chars"
        });

        video.load();

        // The animation
        const tl = gsap.timeline({
            defaults: {
                duration: duration
            },
            onStart: animationStart,
            onComplete: animationDone
        });
        // Move out slide
        tl.to(items[index], { xPercent: outIn[0] });
        // move in slide
        tl.from(items[moveIn], { xPercent: outIn[1] }, "<");
        // Animate text
        tl.set(items[index], { autoAlpha: 0 }); // Hide moved out slide
    }
    function animationStart() {
        container.classList.add("running");
        video.load();
    }
    function animationDone() {
        autoplay = window.setTimeout(slideLogic, timer);
        container.classList.remove("running");
        gsap.set(items, { x: 0 });
    }
    // END ️ Slide animation --------------//

    //--------------------------------//
    // Slider ️ logic
    //--------------------------------//
    function slideLogic(prev, customMoveIn) {
        window.clearTimeout(autoplay); // disable autoplay
        let outIn = [-move, move];
        if (prev) outIn.reverse();
        let moveIn;
        // Check if moveIn is passed with the function
        if (typeof customMoveIn === "undefined") {
            if (prev) {
                moveIn = index === 0 ? itemsMax : index - 1;
            } else {
                moveIn = index === itemsMax ? 0 : index + 1;
            }
        } else {
            moveIn = customMoveIn;
        }
        if (thumbnail) dotActive(moveIn); // Set active dot
        slideAnimation(index, moveIn, outIn); // Animation function
        // Changing the next index
        if (typeof customMoveIn === "undefined") {
            if (prev) {
                index === 0 ? (index = itemsMax) : index--;
            } else {
                index === itemsMax ? (index = 0) : index++;
            }
        } else {
            index === itemsMax ? (index = 0) : (index = customMoveIn++);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The question is unclear. Why is the autoplay attribute set on all the videos if you only want to play the visible video and then slide when it ends? And why does the code use timers for the animation rather than video events?

Comment: @Yogi because thats how it gonna able to slide to next slider. i got your points but don't know how i can resolve the problem could you check the link of codepen?